# Infinite loop on .hover with backgroundImage

Tags: jquery-animate

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.istina').hover(function() {
        animate_loop = function() {
          $(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url(<?php print $base_path . $directory ?>/img/istina-hover.png)').animate({backgroundImage: 'url(/sites/all/themes/ruh/img/istina.png)'}, 500, function() { animate_loop(); } );
      }, function() {
          $(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url(<?php print $base_path . $directory ?>/img/istina.png)');
        }
        }
      )
    });
```

I have a link with class `<a class="istina">some text</a>` i want to change backgroundImage of it on hover and while hover i want to switch between istina.png and istina-hover.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you dont need any javascript to do this, it can be CSS driven...

html:

```
<a class="istina">some text</a>
```

css

```
#istina {  
background-image : url(istina.png); 
}

#istina :hover { 
background-image : url(istina-hover.png); 
}
```

Comment: With just css when you hover it will just change image once, i need that image to be changing all the time when i hovered (istina.png and istina-hover.png)

Comment: what do you mean changing all the time? like its flickering? the code i gave you will change the image every time you change from hover to non-hover....

Comment: indeed, only when you hover! I need to hover (image changing on hovered one) while i hover it would change from istina.png to istina-hover.png (!!! WHILE IM STILL HOVERING !!!) Like non stop animation.